# Drives for Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter

Tags: wireless, ralink, ubuntu-drivers

The thing is, I really don't know what to do. I just installed Ubuntu. I have no internet connection now. I have a Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter. But it's not working.

lsusb detects it (I guess):

```
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

But nothing in that wifi icon. And also 'sudo lshw -C network' only shows Ethernet. Also in one of the post, I've read that Ubuntu 17.04 (which I have) contains it by default. If so why is it not working? Should I do something? By the way, the device was not plugged when installing Ubuntu. Is there a installing-driver-from-ubuntu-cd sort of thing??

Please help. I'm new to Ubuntu.

`rfkill list all` and `sudo modprobe mt7601u` returns nothing. The second one asked for password, though.

**EDIT:** So, I've managed to install driver from a source. Now`dmesg | grep mt76` gives 3 more lines at the beginning:

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
mt7601Usta: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
mt7601Usta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Also `iwconfig` outputs:

```
ra0             Ralink STA
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo modprobe mt7601u` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Updated.

Comment: Now, let's take a look at the log: `dmesg | grep mt76` As the output might be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25647080/

Comment: Please see the long discussion here: https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/issues/64 with the same errors. Have you tried every different USB port? I'm not sure I have any other suggestions.

Comment: What about NDISWrapper? Will that help??

Comment: No, it certainly won't.

Comment: So, I have to switch to another adapter. But it works perfectly fine in Windows

Comment: Did you have to install drivers for it to work in Windows?  I suspect there might be some cheap fakes of these wireless cards and that is why some don't work in Linux

Comment: I did install driver in Windows 7. But in Win10, it got installed automatically.

Comment: Hey guys! I've found the linux driver in the installation cd that came with it. The name of the file is DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2 . I ran the following codes as said in readme. `cd DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913`,`make`. But `make` returned 2 warnings and 1 error as in [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25654004/). What should I do?

Comment: @chili555 I've made some more edits. Have a look

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is an old, old driver, I see nothing additional wrong. Does it scan and see networks? `sudo iwlist ra0 scan` Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e ra0 -e rt2`

Comment: @chili555 The first one returns `unknown command: scan` and the second one returns `usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u`. Same as above

Comment: Does `iwconfig` confirm that the wireless interface is now ra0 or some other? Are, in fact, two drivers loaded? `lsmod | grep -i mt76`

Comment: @chili555 Yes. It is always listed as `ra0`. And the second command returns: `mt7601Usta       602112 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a working solution for this problem. The answer is from [GitHub](https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/issues/64#issuecomment-352250127)

- Download corresponding kernel source from kernel.org. For example: if you have `4.4.0-104-generic` download version 4.4. You can check the current kernel version by running `uname --kernel-release`
- From archive unpack just folder `drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt7601u`
- Edit phy.c. Find function `mt7601u_init_cal` and comment out call `mt7601u_mcu_calibrate(dev, MCU_CAL_RXIQ, 0);` like in **code 1 below**
- Find function `mt7601u_phy_recalibrate_after_assoc` and comment out call `mt7601u_mcu_calibrate(dev, MCU_CAL_DPD, dev->curr_temp);` like in **code 2 below**
- Build module:

  **make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules**
- Remove device

  **sudo rmmod mt7601u**
  **sudo insmod ./mt7601u.ko**
- Insert device
- Check there are no errors in `dmesg` and interface appeared in ip link, check connection stability.
- To make change persistent **till next kernel upgrade**: backup original module and replace with compiled. To find out where is original module run `modinfo mt7601u` (view string filename: */lib/modules/_KERNEL_VERSION_/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt7601u/mt7601u.ko*).

I've tried this method on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.10. Working flawlessly...

Code 1:

```
// ret = mt7601u_mcu_calibrate(dev, MCU_CAL_RXIQ, 0); 
// if (ret) 
// return ret;
// ret = mt7601u_mcu_calibrate(dev, MCU_CAL_DPD, dev->dpd_temp); 
// if (ret) 
// return ret;
```

Code 2:

```
void mt7601u_phy_recalibrate_after_assoc(struct mt7601u_dev *dev)
    { 
    // mt7601u_mcu_calibrate(dev, MCU_CAL_DPD, dev->curr_temp);
       mt7601u_rxdc_cal(dev); 
    }
```

Hope it helps...