# wifi adapter not recognized after driver installation

Tags: networking, drivers

I followed this guide here:
[TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=2620def754eb4d25b5062c3a597bf897)
since I have the same wifi adapter that was working at that point but was giving me much lower speeds than my windows partition.
After rebooting my wifi adapter is not recognized anymore...
It shows in lsusb command.

Any suggestions on how to go back to it?

Edit:
I tried installing from another repository (https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) and this is what I got:

```
dkms status
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Edit:
I get this from uninstalling

```
sudo dkms uninstall 8812au/4.2.3

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  8812au
Version: 4.2.3
Kernel:  5.4.0-66-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

8812au.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-66-generic/
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

dkms status
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: built
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-66-lowlatency, x86_64: installed

sudo dkms remove 8812au/4.2.3 --all

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  8812au
Version: 4.2.3
Kernel:  5.4.0-66-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  8812au
Version: 4.2.3
Kernel:  5.4.0-66-lowlatency (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

8812au.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-66-lowlatency/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.2.3
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
stella@IBP10382:~$ dkms status
stella@IBP10382:~$
```

And after reinstalling, the same

```
stella@IBP10382:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
dkms is already the newest version (2.3-3ubuntu9.7).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-62
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
stella@IBP10382:~$ sudo make dkms_install
make: *** No rule to make target 'dkms_install'.  Stop.
stella@IBP10382:~$ cd rtl8812au/
stella@IBP10382:~/rtl8812au$ sudo make dkms_install
mkdir -p /usr/src/8812au-4.2.3
cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-4.2.3
dkms add -m 8812au -v 4.2.3

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8812au/4.2.3/source ->
                 /usr/src/8812au-4.2.3

DKMS: add completed.
dkms build -m 8812au -v 4.2.3

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.4.0-66-generic..........
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.
dkms install -m 8812au -v 4.2.3

8812au:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version v4.2.3 for 8812au.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-66-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
dkms status
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
stella@IBP10382:~/rtl8812au$ echo 8812au | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
8812au
```

By the way, the driver it was using previously was this: mt76x0u

Many thanks!

Comment: dkms status
8812au, 4.2.3, 5.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) This is what I am getting after this installation (no connection from the wifi adapter)

Comment: Let's first uninstall the modules, and then reinstall from the same repo. (1) `sudo dkms uninstall 8812au/4.2.3` and `sudo dkms remove 8812au/4.2.3 --all` (2) Reinstall as described on the repo using DKMS method.

Comment: Have updated my question, thanks!

Comment: This is the output of lsusb: Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.

Comment: In your original post you said that, you were trying to install `rtl8812au` drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`. While you actually need `MT7601U` drivers for `Device ID 148f:761a`. Please remove the existing drivers as described in my earlier comment.

Comment: After removing existing drivers, please go to this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/terence-deng/mt7601u` for `MT7601U` drivers. First go through their build requirements, and then install the drivers. That's the most latest drivers I could find at the moment.

Comment: If the drivers from `terence-deng` repo don't not work for you then as last resort, go through this AskUbuntu answer. It's a little complex workaround but it's most recent (Feb 2020): `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205254/ralink-tech-mt7601u-wireless-adapter-on-xubuntu/1207160#1207160`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice! I was actually trying to resolve the slow connection with the old driver and that is why I was looking for the rtl one that was supposed to be more stable. Hope I manage to solve this eventually!

Comment: @StellaXaral Drivers are hardware specific. One is not an older version of the other, their for different chipsets, Realtek and Ralink/Mediatek.